# vba Excel 2010 - MouseDown event on Active X Controls Command Button

Tags: excel, vba, function, events, mousedown

On [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716234(v=vs.60).aspx) Microsoft explains how to know if a combinaison of Shift, Ctrl and Alt is pressed when MouseDown event occurs:

`Private Sub Form_MouseDown(Button As Integer, _
      Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
   ShiftTest = Shift And 7
   Select Case ShiftTest
      Case 1 ' or vbShiftMask
         Print "You pressed the SHIFT key."
      Case 2 ' or vbCtrlMask
         Print "You pressed the CTRL key."
      Case 4 ' or vbAltMask
         Print "You pressed the ALT key."
      Case 3
         Print "You pressed both SHIFT and CTRL."
      Case 5
         Print "You pressed both SHIFT and ALT."
      Case 6
         Print "You pressed both CTRL and ALT."
      Case 7
         Print "You pressed SHIFT, CTRL, and ALT."
      End Select
End Sub`

It works just fine. I have many CommandButtons, would it be possible not to copy paste all these lines and replace them by a function called instead ?

This is the idea but it is not working:

`Private Sub CommandButton1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    call test(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
End Sub`

`Private Sub CommandButton2_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    call test(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
End Sub`

Same for CommandButton3 and 4...

`Private Sub test(Button As Integer, _
      Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
   ShiftTest = Shift And 7
   Select Case ShiftTest
      Case 1 ' or vbShiftMask
         Print "You pressed the SHIFT key."
      Case 2 ' or vbCtrlMask
         Print "You pressed the CTRL key."
      Case 4 ' or vbAltMask
         Print "You pressed the ALT key."
      Case 3
         Print "You pressed both SHIFT and CTRL."
      Case 5
         Print "You pressed both SHIFT and ALT."
      Case 6
         Print "You pressed both CTRL and ALT."
      Case 7
         Print "You pressed SHIFT, CTRL, and ALT."
      End Select
End Sub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    test CommandButton1, Shift, X, Y
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    test CommandButton2, Shift, X, Y
End Sub
```